# Creating Google Maps' interface in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, maps, gis, arcgis

I am trying to use the ArcGIS 2.1 JS API to create a custom interface that looks similar to Google Maps.

What is confusing me (particularly with Dojo's layout scheme) is how Google Maps has a map pane that extends the whole width of the page and has a left search results panel that seems to be floating above the map pane.

How does this work in terms of Dojo layouts? I have frustratingly worked with BorderContainers and looked at the documentation for a FloatingPane with no avail.

Any direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what problem you're running into - either troubleshooting or design, but, here is a rigid construct example that might work:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>dojo/google map example</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5.0/dojo/resources/dojo.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script djConfig="parseOnLoad:true" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require( "dijit.layout.BorderContainer" );
dojo.require( "dijit.layout.ContentPane" );
dojo.addOnLoad( function() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.887, -77.016);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng, 
        map: map,
        title:"Hello World!"
    });   
});
</script>

</head>

<body class="claro" style="height:100%;padding:0;margin:0; overflow:hidden">


<div dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" style="height:100%">
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="left" splitter="true" style="width:200px">
        Left search thing
    </div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="top" style="height:100px">
        Top
    </div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="center" style="overflow:hidden">

        <div id="map_canvas" style="height:100%; width:100%"></div>

    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

You can substitute components for expando panes, and other gizmos, but this should technically work and look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/srjBr.png

Comment: Oh, wow. I never knew the `splitter` parameter even existed. Although that's not exactly what I am looking for, it'll do.

Answer (score 3):

Or you could just use the ArcGIS Extension for Google Maps :)

http://resources.esri.com/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/gmaps/