# multiple google map instances with linked zoom/extents

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dojo

Is there a way to 'link' the extents / zooms of multiple google map instances?

I'm working of the dojo example seen here ([Creating Google Maps' interface in Dojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858812/creating-google-maps-interface-in-dojo)) and have modified the code in order to have a second instance of the base map in a new pane.  I will eventually be adding different kml layers of info to the two panes etc but for now i would like to find a way to link the view and extent of the two maps.  i.e. any pan / zoom performed on either of the maps would be reproduced in the other

here's my code so far (pretty new to javascript so please be gentle!!)

```
<html>

<head>
<title>dojo/google map example</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5.0/dojo/resources/dojo.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script djConfig="parseOnLoad:true" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require( "dijit.layout.BorderContainer" );
dojo.require( "dijit.layout.ContentPane" );
dojo.addOnLoad( function intialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(48,-80.624207);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas1"), myOptions);


  });


});




</script>

</head>

<body class="claro" style="height:100%;padding:0;margin:0; overflow:hidden">


<div dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" style="height:100%">
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="left"  style="width:15%">
        Left search thing
    </div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="top" style="height:2%">
        Top
    </div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="center" style="overflow:hidden" >

        <div id="map_canvas" style="height:100%; width:100%"></div>

    </div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="right" style="width:40%" >

        <div id="map_canvas1" style="height:100%; width:100%"></div>

    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Multiple maps are best avoided, otherwise you are increasing the rate at which you eat into your free google quota.

Answer (score 1):

It's quit easy. You may bind a property of a MVCObject to a property of another MVCObject.

The bounded property of Object#1 will be set to the property of Object#2 everytime the property in Object#2 changes.

Maps-instances are MVCObjects, so all you have to do is to bind `zoom` and `center` of `map` to `zoom` and `center` of `map1`:

```
map.bindTo('center',map1,'center');
map.bindTo('zoom',map1,'zoom');
```

Note: there is an syntax-error in your script, remove the   `});` at the end